# Best way to add fields to the output of a View

Tags: entities, views

I have a View which lists contents. I have a few fields which are composite and have a somehow convoluted logics. What I do is to add some "dummy" fields (for example, the nid of content, or the rf (reference) of product) to the View, and then in `hook_views_prerender` I modify the value by the logic. For example:

```
$brand = $view->result[$key]->taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_brand_name;
if($brand == WHATEVER){
   $view->result[$key]->field_field_field_rf_product_3[0]["rendered"]["#markup"] = function_to_substitute_complicated_value($parameters);   
 ...
 }
```

Now, is it good idea to have this dummy field, **field_rf_product_3**, or would it be better to create a new field programmaticaly, and if so, how could it be done to be added at the proper place (after a given rendered field) in the View output?

Comment: It depends on the function. You can generate data in this dummy field, but if you do heavy queries in function_to_substitute_complicated_value it might be better to store the value in a real field, so you don't have to do the query every time the view is loaded. If it a simple function this should work as well.

Comment: The approach of saving the node with the data is very interesting, thanks. I will give it a look. In any case, the question remains, if there is some way of adding fields on the fly, I looked for it but did not find anything that worked or that rendered the field in the correct order.

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood the question. Have a look at the function hook_views_data(). In the bottom of the commens there is a comment by me about how to display a dynamic value.

Comment: That is very interesting. It seems to me that this is the correct way of doing what I done by using that "pseudofield", populating it, which was rather cumbersome. Thanks!

Comment: I'll write you a detailed answer when I am at my pc in an hour or so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you have two options to do this elegantly.

1. [Use the computed field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) (it also includes the storing of the results in the database to save on heavy SQL queries as mentioned in the comments). It comes with a lot of [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/126522) and examples at the bottom of that page.

> Computed Field is a very powerful field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields
>   are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw
>   on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the current
>   user, database tables, you name it. (Feeling the power yet? :) ) You
>   can also choose whether to store your computed field values in the
>   database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on the
>   fly during node views. (Although you should note that Views use
>   requires database stored values.) This field is literally the Swiss
>   Army knife of fields. So start cooking up your PHP based values!

2. Write a custom views field handler (example is for Drupal 7 only!). In drupal 8 some functions like [hook_views_api() have been removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/1875596) and the info file has changed.

This is less flexible and will result in a specific field to choose when building a view. However sometimes less flexible can be desirable.

In order to do this you need to write a custom module. Consisting the following folder and files:

- module_name

  - module_name.info
  - module_name.module
  - views

    - module_name.views.inc
    - module_name_handler_field_custom_field.inc

The .info file describes the module:

```
name = Custom Views field
description = Provides an additional field to Views
core = 7.x
package = Views
dependencies[] = views
files[] = views/module_name_handler_field_custom_field.inc
```

The .module file contains the module, which in this case is only a function to let Views know where to look for its files.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function module_name_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/views',
  );
}
```

The file `module_name.views.inc` performs the logic for Views. If you define a new entity, use [`hook_views_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7.x-3.x). If you alter an existing entity such as a user or a node, use [`hook_views_data_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7) but also look at the example code of `hook_views_data()`.

In order to create a new field based on another field, you can do something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 *
 * Defines a new field with content built by the module_name_handler_field_custom_field class.
 * @see hook_views_data()
 */ 
function hook_views_data_alter(&$data) {
 // This example adds an example field to the users table.
  $data['node']['example_field'] = array(
    'title' => t('Example field'),
    'help' => t('Some example content'),
    'real field' => 'field_existing_base_field', // Enter the base fields system name here.
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'module_name_handler_field_custom_field',
    ),
  );
}
```

Finally the handler, which composes the field. Here we can alter the output of the field using the real field we defined above as input.

```
class module_name_handler_field_custom_field extends views_handler_field {
  /**
   * Render a computed field value (multiplied by 5).
   */
  function render($values) {
    // Load real field value.
    $real_value = $this->get_value($values);
    // Generate new value.
    $value = function_to_substitute_complicated_value($real_value);
    return $this->sanitize_value($value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Very complete and detailed answer, thank you  very much. I am giving a change to the Computed Field Module, but I think that definitely the winner is the custom Views handler, it is also very valuable to see how to extend other modules.